# What does "T moment" mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

This might not relate directly to Korean language but I've heard this (so I assumed its a slang) when I'm watching a Korean show (I can't cite or reference it since I've long forgotten the stuff I have consumed and just remembered the word and asked today) when kind of replied to someone who bragged as a joke.

It went kind of like *"Yeah, I think I'm really handsome today"* *"(acting like they heard something ridiculous) That's kind of a T moment"*

I'd be glad if someone helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer and it's actually funny because it was actually an inside joke between the people. They're referring to MBTI types and their functions (like how others would be like with their zodiac signs) like INTP, INTJ, (they're referring to the third function of the MBTI of the person)

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of it and Googling in Korean shows nothing. It could be that the first person's name starts with a T, but even then natives would be extremely unlikely to express it like that (either in English "Tee" or even less likely, 티읕). Could just be an inside reference. In any case it doesn't seem to be something in general use.

Comment: Thank you for this very eloquent answer. I actually found out it was an inside reference and you were right!